# Php Select Option

Tags: php, database, select

Database:

articles: id_article, despcription.

data: id, id_article, amount.

So my problem is that i would like to insert in database "data" the id_article but on selected option appear the description of the article ( desc ), and not the id_article.

Would like to solve this problem, all the help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code that you have written so far, and a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Glad to see that you solved it. If you could edit your question to be more clear, the post could be re-opened. Then you can tell us what the solution was - it may be of help to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest to use id_article as the value of the option.

```
<option value="id_article">description</option>
```